# Spark Cost of reading from source with multiple filter vs reading as a whole

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

On reading larger then available memory parquet file from source like S3 in to different dataframe say dfa, dfb, dfc with different filter condition a, b, c. Will each dataframe read only the part of the data.?
As spark supports lazy evaluation, so total cost in terms of time as reading all in to dataframe with out any condition.

Please let me know if my understanding is wrong here
Overall here is the pseudo code for filtered operation:

```
df_raw = spark.read.parquet("s3://path")

df_a = df_core.filter(df_core.Column1.isin("condition A))
df_b = df_core.filter(df_core.Column1.isin("condition B))
df_c = df_core.filter(df_core.Column1.isin("condition C))

df_a=df_a.repartition(2200,["ColumnA","ColumnB"])
df_b=df_b.repartition(1500,["ColumnA","ColumnC"])
df_c=df_c.repartition(800,["ColumnA"])

df_new_intermediate = df_a.unionAll(df_b)
df_new = df_new_intermediate.unionAll(df_c)
df_new.groupBy("ColumnA","ColumnB","ColumnC")
```

Comment: Since you are using a unionAll on df a.b and c, can't you `isin` be reduced to `condition A || condition B || condition c`?

Comment: @philantrovert: datasets i am working is largely skewed so i was using different partition for each dataframe hoping to better distribute the data, hence combining will not help here. I have added repartitioning code on above.